# iteration equals filename bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have got a little script in bash and i have a problem with equals. I have 80 files in .mp4 and i want to join all movie to 1, so I wrote a script. My filenames are for example 2.mp4 5.mp4 10.mp4 etc... They are not in order and i dont have for example 13,14,15.mp4 but i have 12.mp4 and 16.mp4

I want to equals iteration with filename in my loop function and i dont know how...

```
for((i=1; i <= 200; i++))
{    
        if[ -f "$i.mp4" == WHAT HERE??? ] ; then
                mkvmerge -o /home/ftpuser/movies/Main/out/$i.mp4 /home/ftpuser/movies/Movie/test.mp4 \+ /home/ftpuser/movies/addMovie/$i.mp4
        else
                echo -e "${RED}Null${NC}"

fi
}
```

Comment: If your numbers are small, then you can iterate over all of the possible values without much load, but if your files are named `3459087.mp4`, `9387540.mp4`, etc., then iterating over all *possible* names is nonsense.  How about iterating like this: `for f in *.mp4; do ...; done`  That would be way more concise.

Comment: This is very inefficient. You can just pass the full list of files to `mkvmerge` in a single command and concatenate them in a single pass. It also has nothing at all to do with `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if [ -f ${i}.mp4 ] ; then` this. If file exists, `then` case will run. Else, `else` will.

Check that you run script in the directory with mp4 files. If you are not, write full path to your file in if, like: `if [ -f /pull/path/to/your/file/${i}.mp4 ]; then`

You also can try to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

for files in /full/path/to/your/mp4/files/*
do
    name=$(basename ${files})
    mkvmerge -o /home/ftpuser/movies/Main/out/${name} /home/ftpuser/movies/Movie/test.mp4 \+ /home/ftpuser/movies/addMovie/${name}
done
```

Here you needs not `if` statements.

Comment: @Mdr92 np. Have edited last solution. Check it, were writing without access to linux-terminal, so it can have a little issues mb. Or just use first :)